# Windows user profile seems to be blocking certificate auth on webservice calls

Tags: security, delphi, authentication, certificate

I have a Delphi app that's running on Windows Server 2003.  The app communicates with a webservice on another server that is protected by a Cisco ACE XML Gateway requiring a certificate for client authentication.  When I run my app as a local administrator on the box I have no problems connecting to the webservice.  When I run it as a member of a different group policy that has less rights than local administrator I get the error: "An error occurred in the secure channel support - [*endpoint* - *soapaction*]"

I know the user can connect to the ACE because if I have it provide the wrong cert, I get a 'Forbidden' message back.

Does anyone know of any user/group policy rights in Windows that could cause this?  I'd really appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 2):

It turns out it was a user privilege issue.  I was able to run winhttpcertcfg to grant access to the cert to the set of domain users I wanted, and my calls now go through successfully.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like an access issue, to perhaps the windows temp directory, or rsabase.dll.

i suggest you use [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to monitor the process, and see if access is denied to a resource.